# Как продолжить настройку FCM после регистрации приложения?

Tags: fcm

Для отправки сообщения или звонка из своего приложения необходимо разбудить принимающий телефон с режима DOZE. Подскажите, как и где создать сообщение с данными FCM,без уведомления,без своего сервера и без админа.